# I have several of these in my Android project in Eclipse - what is this?

Tags: android, eclipse

What kind of folder type is this and how can I create this?

The name is basically a source folder hierachy of a project library I include. But I do not know what this actually is and how to create this. Looking at the file structre in Finder I don't see anything. So I guess it must be some kind of link or so.

this is the symbol I try to understand -> [image]

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know what you are even asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a folder Icon.

Top Right + mark kind indicates it is a source.

Bottom Right with ! indicates that there are some warnings in your code. Look for the Errorlog to remove the warnings.

This is created by Eclipse, as soon as you create a new package, which internally creates a folder for each part of the package name.

Example: If you have com.android.myproject

then eclipse, will create a folder for Src, inside this a com foler, then inside this an android folder and finally myproject folder.